# Could not find play-services-auth-base-license.aar - Ionic android build failed

Tags: android, cordova, ionic2

Error: /project/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

A problem occurred configuring root project 'project'.
Here is the exact error:

> Could not find play-services-auth-base-license.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-base-license:11.8.0).

Searched in the following locations with no help:

https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-auth-base-license/11.8.0/ play-services-auth-base-license-11.8.0.aar

Few days ago all was fine, today i had tried rebuild app (without any changes) got Error. This error is only for Android build for iOS its working.

Anybody knows reason? Error seems to come after an update.

I had checked plugins without spec version

cordova-plugin-googleplus
cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing
cordova-plugin-google-conversion
cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview

all from them have same version as two days ago
another plugins have spec

cli 6.5.0

```
<preference name="pgb-builder-version" value="1" />
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />  
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="26" />  
<plugin name="cordova-android-support-gradle-release" source="npm">  
<variable name="ANDROID_SUPPORT_VERSION" value="26.0.0" />  
</plugin>
```

Please guide if anybody got to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

specifying my dependencies on build.gradle fixed this problem on my end by aligning all version of com.google.firebase like this:

```
   dependencies {
       implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
      // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
      implementation(project(path: "CordovaLib"))
      compile "com.android.support:customtabs:26.+"
      compile "com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1+"
      compile "com.google.gms:google-services:+"
      compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:11.+"
      compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.+"
      compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.+"
      compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.+"
      compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-config:11.+"
      compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:11.+"
      compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.+"
      compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:11.+"
     // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END
    }
```

The above was changed to: 11.+ from previously: +